# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Profession'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I have to add select list to registration page. And I want to save selected item in datebase. I have something like that:

In view page:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Profession, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ProfessionList"])%>                   
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Profession)%>
```

In model class:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Profession")]
public string Profession { get; set; }
```

And in controller:

```
ViewData["ProfessionList"] =
                new SelectList(new[] { "Prof1", "Prof2", "Prof3", "Prof4", "Prof5"}
                .Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
                "value", "text");
```

And I am getting error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Profession'.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Cast it in "SelectList", why are you casting it in  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ?? DropDownListFor  methods accepts selectList.

Comment: I cast it in "SelectList", but i get the same error. I think that it is expecting IEnumerable<SelectListItem> thats why I am using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just define SelectList in you view like that:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Profession, new SelectList(new string[] {"Prof1", "Prof2", "Prof3", "Prof4", "Prof5"}, "Prof1"))%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Profession)%>
```

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend the usage of view models instead of ViewData. So:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Profession")]
    public string Profession { get; set; } 

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProfessionList { get; set; }
}
```

and in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var professions = new[] { "Prof1", "Prof2", "Prof3", "Prof4", "Prof5" }
         .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x, Text = x });
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        ProfessionList = new SelectList(professions, "Value", "Text")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Profession, Model.ProfessionList) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Profession) %>
```